# IF statement not working in VBA

Tags: ms-access, if-statement, vba

I am self-learning VBA and trying to write a little program does the following

1.asks users to enter a number between 10 to 20 in a textbox
2. When a button is clicked, the code will check the number entered in the textbox.If it is between 10 and 20, then a message will be displayed. If the number entered is not between 10 and 20 then the user will be invited to try a gain, and whatever was entered in the textbox will be erased.

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
Me.Text3.SetFocus
inumber = Val(Text3.Text)
If inumber >= 10 & inumber <= 20 Then
MsgBox ("The number you entered is: ") & inumber
Else
Text3.Text = ""
MsgBox ("Please try again")
End If

End Sub
```

However, I don't think the else part of my codes is working. If I enter 5, it will display 5 instead of the message box. Could anyone please let me know if I have missed anything at all.

Thanks in advance. Happy Holidays.

Comment: if you are defining `Form_customer_test ` somewhere, then the `If` should be `If Form_customer_test >= 10 And inumber <= 20 Then` . But I think you meant `If inumber >= 10 And inumber <= 20 Then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below. `&` is for string concatenation in VB. `And` should be used in VB

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
    Me.Text3.SetFocus
    inumber = Val(Text3.Text)
    If inumber >= 10 And inumber <= 20 Then
        MsgBox ("The number you entered is: ") & inumber
    Else
        Text3.Text = ""
        MsgBox ("Please try again")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That was it! Thanks, it works now. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
If Form_customer_test >= 10 & inumber <= 20 Then
```

should be:

```
If inumber >= 10 & inumber <= 20 Then
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I am sorry, that was a typo, I actually had it as inumber instead of form_customer_test. I don't know how that got into it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Confirm: use "And" or "Or" for logical operators